# How to solve 'Parameter '~moveit_controller_manager' not specified'?

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I run: roslaunch sam_moveit_wizard_generated move_group.launch

It says:

```
[ INFO] [1400647657.748106413, 748.461000000]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State Path Constraints'
[FATAL] [1400647657.809613293, 748.476000000]: Parameter '~moveit_controller_manager' not specified. This is needed to identify the plugin to use for interacting with controllers. No paths can be executed.
[ INFO] [1400647657.826129681, 748.479000000]: Trajectory execution is managing controllers
```

and I try to run:

```
sam@sam:~/code/groovy_overlay/src/sam_moveit_learning/bin$ rosrun sam_moveit_learning pose right_arm 0.7 -0.2 0.7 0 0 0
[ INFO] [1400647661.271172191, 749.458000000]: Ready to take MoveGroup commands for group right_arm.
[ INFO] [1400647661.271335019, 749.458000000]: Move to : x=0.700000, y=-0.200000, z=0.700000, roll=0.000000, pitch=0.000000, yaw=0.000000
[ INFO] [1400647662.016181981, 749.640000000]: ABORTED: Solution found but controller failed during execution
^Csam@sam:~/code/groovy_overlay/src/sam_moveit_learning/bin$
```

I also got this error:

```
[ INFO] [1400647661.483935586, 749.503000000]: Path simplification took 0.016063 seconds
[ERROR] [1400647662.013314708, 749.640000000]: Unable to identify any set of controllers that can actuate the specified joints: [ r_elbow_flex_joint r_forearm_roll_joint r_shoulder_lift_joint r_shoulder_pan_joint r_upper_arm_roll_joint r_wrist_flex_joint r_wrist_roll_joint ]
[ERROR] [1400647662.013418353, 749.640000000]: Apparently trajectory initialization failed
```

I try to fix it by install but not works:

```
sam@sam:~/code/groovy_overlay/src/sam_moveit_learning/bin$ sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-pr2-moveit-plugins
[sudo] password for sam: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ros-groovy-pr2-moveit-plugins is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 168 not upgraded.
sam@sam:~/code/groovy_overlay/src/sam_moveit_learning/bin$
```

How to solve it?
Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/167501/how-to-solve-%27parameter-%27%7Emoveit_controller_manager%27-not-specified%27?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2014-05-20

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you create the moveit config by yourself for your robot Sam, using the setup assistant for instance or by hand?
If yes, using the setup assistant is not enough to use Moveit, you need to provide Moveit a way to control your robot, through a controller manager.

By default, the setup assistant creates a fake_controller_manager. See the default fake_controller_manager.launch.xml file in the launch/ directory. You my create your own controller manager, or check if it's not already in the package moveit_robots.

This controller manager is launched in trajectory_execution.launch.

See http://moveit.ros.org/wiki/Executing_Trajectories_with_MoveIt!#The_MoveIt.21_Controller_Manager_Plugin

---

Originally posted by [courrier](https://answers.ros.org/users/10836/courrier/) with karma: 454 on 2014-09-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zweistein](https://answers.ros.org/users/4023/zweistein/) on 2015-10-08**:
The link does not work any more and I have the same issue, but I used Moveit assistant and I am using the  dynemixel_motor controll manager. I feel that I missed something to set up in the launch files, but I can't figure out what. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This might be relevant i think: http://answers.ros.org/question/192739/implement-moveit-on-real-robot/

---

Originally posted by [anonymous8676](https://answers.ros.org/users/8676/anonymous8676/) with karma: 327 on 2014-10-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2